# How to install monodevelop 5.8

Tags: mono, monodevelop

According to [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/) monodevelop/xamarin studio 5.8 is out.

But on the official repositories, I can only get 5.7

Is there a way to get the latest version?

Comment: Try this: https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop-beta

Comment: Thanks! Have you tried it? (last time I installed monodevelop from a ppa, it messed my configuration). If you are positive that this works without side effects you can propose it as an answer.

Comment: You asked about the last version.

Comment: It works perfectly (MD 5.9), thanks! If you want to create an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Thx, here is the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ermshiperete/+archive/ubuntu/monodevelop-beta) for the latest beta release:

> A custom build of the latest beta release of MonoDevelop (built from
>   the tag in git) that can be installed parallel to the version included
>   in the official Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop-beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-current
```

The latest version today is *5.9.0.427* for Precise, Trusty, Utopic and Vivid.

If there are problems during installation, similar to mine in Vivid, then just install the dependencies manually, e.g.:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-sharp-4.0
sudo apt-get install gnome-sharp-4.0
sudo apt-get install mono-addins-4.0
sudo apt-get install jscall-sharp-0
```

The above were mine, you might have more/less then these.